# Flattening 3-Dimensional data to elongated 2-D in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I have data with dim 10,5,2 (t,x,y) and I want to convert it to dimensions 10*5,3. i.e to append every t frame to (x,y) frame with t value.

eg:

```
data[1,,]=
x y
1 2
1 3

data[2,,]=
x y
5 2
1 6
```

I would like to convert this data to flatten array like this

```
x y t
1 2 1
1 3 1
5 2 2
1 6 2
```

I was looking if there is already R function to do this or I'd do it by looping every t array and add the recreated array at bottom of main array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a <- array(1:8, c(2,2,2))
a[1,,]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    5
#[2,]    3    7

a[2,,]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    6
#[2,]    4    8

m <- matrix(aperm(a, c( 2, 1, 3)), nrow=prod(dim(a)[2:3]))
cbind(m, rep(seq_len(dim(a)[2]), each=dim(a)[1]))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    5    1
#[2,]    3    7    1
#[3,]    2    6    2
#[4,]    4    8    2
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted!

Comment: @AnkurGupta: the first line can be simplified to `m <- apply(a, 3, c)`, which is prettier, but slower for large matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach:

```
a <- array(c(1,5,1,1,2,2,3,6), dim = c(2,2,2) )
do.call('rbind',lapply(1:dim(a)[3], function(x) cbind(a[x,,], t = x)))
         t
[1,] 1 2 1
[2,] 1 3 1
[3,] 5 2 2
[4,] 1 6 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Also:

If `a`is the array.

```
ft <- ftable(a)
cbind(ft[,1:2], as.numeric(factor(gsub("\\_.*","",row.names(as.matrix(ft))))))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    1
[2,]    1    3    1
[3,]    5    2    2
[4,]    1    6    2
```